# Routes are keeping certain URLs in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I made a page for users to update their specific information, but when I access this page, by clicking on my tags, "user-edit" is added to the link. Then when I click on the logo in my header, instead of taking me to "http://myapp.test/index," it takes me to "http://myapp.test/user-edit/index." I guess it could be a problem with the route, but I can't figure out how to fix it, and my route seems to be clean.

**Routes**

```php
Route::get("user-edit/{id}", [UserController::class, 'showData']);
Route::post("user-edit", [UserController::class, 'updateData']);
```

Finally, the action of my form is `{{ url('user-edit') }}`.

Comment: How do you assemble the link on your logo?

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
it's : <a href="index" class="logo">LOGO</a>

Comment: Make that `href="/index"` and you're good to go (`href="index"` starts from the current directory and "just" adds `index`, `href="/index"` starts from the topmost/root of your site). I suggest reading about [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) and using them, makes linking a lot easier imho

Comment: It woked ! thanks a lot !